# How to print object element for each internal array element in jq

Tags: json, export-to-csv, jq

I have JSON that looks like this:

**test.json**

```
[
  {
    "item1": {
      "item2": 123,
      "array1": [
        {
          "item3": 456,
          "item4": "teststring"
        },
        {
          "item3": 789,
          "item4": "teststring2"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I am trying to print it out in the following format:

```
123, 456, teststring
123, 789, teststring2
```

I tried to do it like this:

```
cat test.json | jq -r '.[].item1.item2, (.[].item1.array1[] | .item3, .item4)' | xargs printf "%s, %s, %s\n"
```

But the result is that `item2` is printed, followed by `item3` and `item4` in the first line, and then only `item3` and `item4` are printed in the next line, like so:

```
123, 456, teststring
789, teststring2,
```

How can I make the element on the outside of the array print for every set of elements that are printed from within the array?

Comment: do you want `123, 789, teststring` or `123, 789, teststring2`?

Comment: Teststring2 on the 2nd line, thanks for spotting I corrected it

Comment: Will the order of the item3/item4 keys in the objects in the array always be the same?

Comment: @peak yes, the ordering will always be the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing the processing of the output with shell's `printf()` with `xargs` is not needed as you can do the processing entirely in `jq` itself.

You need to iterate over the values of `.item3` and `.item4` each time for one unique value of `.item2`. To have the result in proper CSV format, format the array using `@csv` and for tabular representation you can use `@tsv`

```
jq -r '.[].item1 as $data | $data.array1[] | [ $data.item2 , .item3 , .item4 ] | @csv' json
```

Also it does not make sense to lose quotes around the `.item4` values in your expected output, as they are the expected to be retained in a valid JSON string attribute.

If you still need to loose the quotes and represent them as raw strings, you can use `join` on the formed array

```
jq -r '.[].item1 as $data | $data.array1[] | [ ($data.item2|tostring) , (.item3|tostring) , .item4 ]|join(", ")'
```

Answer (score 1):

This would help

https://jqplay.org/s/KLPXwB7Ey_

```
.[].item1 as $item | $item.array1[] | $item.item2 , .item3 , .item4
```

Comment: not quite complete. OP needs the result in a CSV format